# Autenticação, email / senha e saber qual é o banco correto

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

A ideia é uma aplicação SaaS.

Aonde haverá apenas 1 único deploy. e os clientes serão separados por banco

Feito isso, haverá uma tela de login, onde é informado login(email)/senha

Mas como faço para encaminhar ele para o banco correto ? como poderia ser essa estrutura de tabelas/classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1: Faça dois contextos: um de usuários, outro de tabelas do sistema

Penso que a ideia é ter todos os contextos iguais, com apenas a `Connection String` diferente. Neste caso, é interessante ter um contexto comum:

```
public class MeuContexto : DbContext 
{
    public MeuContexto(String connectionString) : base(connectionString) 
    { }
    // Coloque seus DbSets aqui
}
```

E outro contexto que guarde apenas dados do usuário:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext 
{
    public MeuContexto() : base("DefaultConnection") 
    { }
    // Coloque seus DbSets de usuário aqui
}
```

Neste contexto de usuário, você pode ter um *Model* que guarde as `Connection Strings`.

## 2: Implemente um `ActionFilter` que determine qual `Connection String` será usada

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var usersContext = new usersContext();

        var user = usersContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name);

        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["connectionString"] = user.Company.ConnectionString;

        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

## 3. Recupere a `Connection String` dentro da sua `Action`

Neste caso, você terá que iniciar um contexto para cada `Action`.

```
[CustomActionFilter]
public class MeuController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new MeuContexto(HttpContext.Items["connectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            // Use seu contexto aqui normalmente
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a ideia é boa...mas farei um pouco diferente, numa simples ligação user -> empresa, aonde o mesmo terá apenas o nome do banco, entao o 1 contexto faz o login e repassa o nome do banco para o segundo contexto, logo o 1 contexto é apenas para login e info do usuário e o segundo, para todo o resto do sistema, o que acha? virei a noite pensando nisso, rsrsr

Comment: @Rod Sim, é exatamente isso que minha resposta coloca. Você pode perfeitamente trocar a `Connection String` do exemplo pra colocar o nome desse banco, e configurar o `Web.config` para ter as `Connection Strings`. O que mudaria é a maneira de iniciar o contexto, em que você passa como argumento o nome da conexão, e não a conexão em si.